# Jackson - deserialise a single value with Jackson's deserialisers

Tags: java, jackson

I have a Jackson ObjectMapper with a custom deserializer for java.time.Instant (and other types). How do I read a single value instead of a full JSON blob, e.g.

```
objectMapper.readValue("2017-02-01T00:00:00Z", Instant.class)
```

Clarification in response to comments asking for a use case:

I have already parsed the JSON into

```
class MyConfiguration {
    public Instant someField;
    public Map<String, String> otherFields;

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, String> any() {
        return otherFields;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void set(String name, String value) {
        otherFields.put(name, value);
    }
}
```

Now I have:

```
interface Something {
    void init(MyConfiguration config)
}

class Something2 implements Something {
    public void init(MyConfiguration config) {
         //Here I would be like the implementation to be able to 
         //get a value from otherFields deserialised to a specified type.
    }
}
```

I'm aware that I could map them directly using `@JsonSubTypes` but I'm trying to make the system extensible and unaware of the implementations.

Comment: What is the use case for this? Doesn't make much sense to be using a JSON library if you don't have JSON. Just use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-

Comment: @pedromss I'm parsing a YAML file for configuration that has some dynamic properties (a Map<String, String>) and I'm trying to let different implementations of an interface pull properties out with a specific type e.g. `<T> T getProperty(String prop, Map<String, String> map, Class<T> clazz)`

Comment: I'm still confused. You have some JSON, and you want to extract some field and only deserialize that?

Comment: @bcoughlan your example doesn't make much sense. However if you say you have a yaml file maybe this is what you want: https://dzone.com/articles/read-yaml-in-java-with-jackson :)

Comment: The text `2017-02-01T00:00:00Z` is not valid JSON text, so you cannot do that. `"2017-02-01T00:00:00Z"` would be a valid JSON string, so `readValue("\"2017-02-01T00:00:00Z\"", Instant.class)` might potentially work.

Comment: I've updated the question with an example of what I'm trying to do

Comment: @Andreas I thought of that but would have to encode multiline strings and escape quotes correctly. I tried constructing an array with just the string in it using the Jackson API, serialising that and then deserialising it with readValue, but that's too inefficient for my tastes.

Comment: If you want the text `2017-02-01T00:00:00Z` to be "deserialized" to an `Instant`, just call `Instant.parse()`. Why ask Jackson to try to do it? That would be *too inefficient*, and you just stated a dislike for inefficient code.

Comment: @Andreas Because I have a bunch of custom deserialisers already for known properties and I want to avoid duplicating that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, use `convertValue` on the constructed ObjectMapper:

```
objectMapper.convertValue("2017-10-02T01:02:03Z", Instant.class)
```